# Visual Studio Load Tests with XUnit

Tags: performance, visual-studio, testing, xunit.net

We need to create load and stress tests for a cloud application. Most tests will have to be coded instead of being recorded. Thus we need to integrate unit tests in the text mix.

Currently, we are creating a spike with Visual Studio 2015 Load Test Framework. We want to run the load tests from our local infrastructure as well as use Azure's cloud testing.

We would rather use XUnit instead of MS Test to write the unit tests. Is that possible? Do we have to write an plugin to achieve that?

Comment: Of course you can use xunit.net to write your unit tests.To run them download xunit runner and use visual studio test explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413727/can-i-add-nunit-3-tests-to-visual-studio-2015-load-tests/43911543#43911543) for the answer. Both NUnit and XUnit tests can't be added to a load test.