# Can I add NUnit 3 tests to Visual Studio 2015 load tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit, load-testing

I have a testing automation framework written in C# with unit tests written in **NUnit** (*not MSTest*). I created a new **Visual Studio Load Test** configuration and I was expecting to be able to add these NUnit tests to the load test, however Visual Studio (2015) is not listing them. I have the NUnit 3 Test Adapter installed already. Can I add NUnit tests to VS load tests or do they have to be MSTest unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

Until now there is no package or workaround, other then converting your NUnit tests to MSTests, to add your NUnit tests to a LoadTests. The same problem also applies for XUnit test. I hope MS will enable the possibility to add XUnit and NUnit tests to a LoadTest.

A solution is that you can convert you NUnit test:
http://www.stormbase.net/2010/01/12/converting-from-nunit-to-mstest/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Try uninstalling the Nunit extension and readding it.