# Nunit with Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have a testing automation framework written in C# with unit tests written in NUnit (not MSTest). I created a new Visual Studio Load Test configuration and I was expecting to be able to add these NUnit tests to the load test, however Visual Studio (2015) is not listing them. I have the NUnit 3 Test Adapter installed already. Can I add NUnit tests to VS load tests or do they have to be MSTest unit tests?

Comment: Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413727/can-i-add-nunit-3-tests-to-visual-studio-2015-load-tests/43911543#43911543) for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your 'Configuration Manager' in Build is not set to x64

Answer (score 0):

the answer is quite simple though I am speaking of 2018 and VS 2017 15.9:

You cannot add NUnit tests to VS load tests. Even MSTest V2 unit tests may not work. only MStest.